# How to solve a binary optimization problem with linear programming in ortools / cpmodel?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, or-tools, scipy-optimize, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to optimize a binary problem for a website of mine.

The data contains roughly 75 items and each of the items has **a weight** (between 50 and 1000) and **a price** attached to it. Here's a data snippet:

```
{"weighting":{
      "0":500,
      "1":50,
      "2":50,
      "3":50,
      "4":250,
      "5":1000
   },
   "price":{
      "0":4,
      "1":78,
      "2":75,
      "3":170,
      "4":5,
      "5":4
   }
}
```

I calculate the expected value of the whole data set with

exp_val = (w<sub>1</sub> p<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>2</sub> p<sub>2</sub> + ... + w<sub>n</sub> p<sub>n</sub>) / sum(w<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>2</sub> + ... w<sub>n</sub>)

with

sum(w<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>2</sub> + ... w<sub>n</sub>) = 23665 (considering all items)

So far so good, but now comes the tricky part. Not all items are desired, that is, they are worth less and / or have a high weighting which dilutes the pool I can draw from.

By "blocking" or **removing up to 3 items** I can draw from the remaining items only, and by doing so maximizing the expedted value function. The question is: Which items to remove? As the prices vary over time, I have to check the items to remove on a regular basis.

I have started by simply removing the items with the highest weights and the smallest price, but I'm sure this only represents a local optimum and there would be a more optimal strategy.

After checking some websites, it seems that Mixed-integer linear programming (MILP) or in particular BILP (binary ...) can solve my issue, and I found https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html but wasn't able to make it work, as I'm stuck translating my problem into code. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Before writing the code, you should formulate your optimization problem on paper properly. To get you started: Introduce a binary variable x_i that is 1 if the item i is selected and 0 otherwise. Then, you want to maximize sum(y * x_i * w_i * p_i) subject to the constraint 1/sum(x_i * w_i) = y. Note that the second constraint is equivalent to 1 = sum(y * x_i * w_i) and you can linearize the products y * x_i, see [this post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

**1. Make the results trackable**

In cpmodel from ortools you can do so by introducing a class with

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp 

class VarArraySolutionPrinter(cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
"""Print intermediate solutions."""

def __init__(self, variables):
    cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
    self.__variables = variables
    self.__solution_count = 0

def on_solution_callback(self):
    self.__solution_count += 1
    for v in self.__variables:
        print('%s=%i' % (v, self.Value(v)), end=' ')
    print()

def solution_count(self):
    return self.__solution_count
```

and than structure your code like this

```
# ############################################
# content of your objective function goes here
# ############################################

# solve the model
solver = cp.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver?hl=de
# debugging
solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter([objective, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi])
solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True

# inspect the solution
objective_function_value = solver.ObjectiveValue()
solution_info = solver.SolutionInfo()
status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
```

note that in

```
solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter([objective, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi])
```

you want to add the variable names, i.e. using the third argument (str) when creating a variable:

```
xi_wi = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, "xi_wi")
```

**2. Create the model**

With that out of the way I found that I didn't had to follow Jonis advice because cpmodel from ortool can handel binary variables itself. This code works for me:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

# w_default = weighting
# chaos = price
data = {"w_default":{
  "0":500,
  "1":50,
  "2":50,
  "3":50,
  "4":250,
  "5":1000
},
"chaos":{
  "0":4,
  "1":78,
  "2":75,
  "3":170,
  "4":5,
  "5":4
   }
}

model = cp.CpModel()
num_items = len(data["w_default"])

# create boolean coefficients
dv_select_items = {i: model.NewBoolVar("item_" + str(i)) for i in data["w_default"]}

# constraint: remove exactly 3 items
model.Add(sum(dv_select_items[i] for i in dv_select_items) == num_items - 3)

# ##### numerator equation #####
constant = 1000
# x_i * w_i * p_i // sum of weightings * prices = 200.000 -> UB 500.000 to give some space?
xi_wi_pi = model.NewIntVar(50000 * constant, 500000 * constant, "xi_wi_pi")
model.Add(xi_wi_pi == sum(
    dv_select_items[i] * data["w_default"][i] * data["chaos"][i] * constant for i in dv_select_items))

##### denominator equation #####
# xi_wi // sum of weightings 23665: 20665 with 3 blocked
lb_weights = int(tot_weight * 0.75)
xi_wi = model.NewIntVar(lb_weights, tot_weight, "xi_wi")
model.Add(xi_wi == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["w_default"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

objective = model.NewIntVar(0, 100 * constant, "objective")
model.AddDivisionEquality(objective, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi)

# set target
model.Maximize(objective)

# solve the model
solver = cp.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver?hl=de
# debugging
solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter([objective, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi])
solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True

# inspect the solution
objective_function_value = solver.ObjectiveValue()
solution_info = solver.SolutionInfo()
status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
```

**3. Scale the nominator because AddDivisionEquality round to integers**

You might be wondering why I have added a constant in the code (it doesn't work without it). This is because

```
model.AddDivisionEquality(objective, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi)
```

always rounds the result to an integer value and because the results are in the range of 8.something the objective function always returned 8. However, if you multiply the numerator with 1000, 8.3456 now becomes 8345 and 8.4334 becomes 8433 and thus can be evaluated correctly.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem. Also, many thanks to Joni and Barthendu for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging @joni's comments, I have translated it into code. Multiplication of decision variables is not linear, and you will have to linearize the products by adding another intermediate continuous decision variable.

However, if you use Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver (which I have used), it can handle a few non-linear operations such multiplication, division etc of decision variables, which a pure linear solver would not support.

Code listing

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

model = cp.CpModel()

data = {"weighting":{
      "0":500,
      "1":50,
      "2":50,
      "3":50,
      "4":250,
      "5":1000
   },
   "price":{
      "0":4,
      "1":78,
      "2":75,
      "3":170,
      "4":5,
      "5":4
   }
}

num_items = len(data["weighting"])

dv_select_items = {i : model.NewBoolVar("item_" + i) for i in data["weighting"]}

# constraint : keep only 3 items
model.Add(sum(dv_select_items[i] for i in dv_select_items) == 3)


y = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, "")

x_i_w_i_p_i = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, "") # x_i * w_i * p_i
model.Add(x_i_w_i_p_i == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["weighting"][i] * data["price"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

y_x_i_w_i_p_i = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000000000, "") # y * x_i * w_i * p_i
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(y_x_i_w_i_p_i, [x_i_w_i_p_i, y])

# 1 = sum(y * x_i * w_i)  # constraint
x_i_w_i = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, "")
model.Add(x_i_w_i == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["weighting"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

y_x_i_w_i = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000000000, "")
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(y_x_i_w_i, [x_i_w_i, y])

remaining = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "")
model.Add(1000000 == y_x_i_w_i + remaining)
# 1 = sum(y * x_i * w_i) 
# with above y will be fractional. Now, CP-SAT solver does not support
# fractional values. With using integer values (for y) there is no
# gurantee that 1 = sum(y * x_i * w_i), hence adding "remaining" part
# but we should always try to make "remaining" as close to zero

model.Maximize(y_x_i_w_i_p_i)
solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

model.Minimize(remaining)
model.Add(y_x_i_w_i_p_i >= int(solver.ObjectiveValue()))
solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model) 


# inspect the solution
objective_function_value = solver.ObjectiveValue()

[(i, solver.Value(dv_select_items[i])) for i in dv_select_items]
# 2st, 3th and 4th item gets selected
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort. This removes the most profitable items though. With the example data the expected value is 0.18. If you remove item 2, 4 and 6, the expected value goes down to 0.11. I will look further into this to find a solution!

Comment: I wasn't able to make your code work but have iterated on it. The results are in another comment in this thread. Could you please check it and see why it is still not working for me? The objective function returns 0 all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized that one constraint was not specified correctly - "model.AddMultiplicationEquality(y_x_i_w_i, [x_i_w_i, y])" (this is correct version, earlier one had a mistake). I have provided the revised code above.

Now, items 2,3,4 gets selected. Does this selection makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following:

```
# new data!
data = {"w_default": {
    "0": 500,
    "1": 250,
    "2": 500,
    "3": 1000,
    "4": 1000,
    "5": 500
},
    "chaos": {
        "0": 8,
        "1": 5,
        "2": 5,
        "3": 4,
        "4": 4,
        "5": 2
    }
}

UB = 10000000
model = cp.CpModel()

num_items = len(data["w_default"])

# create boolean coefficients
dv_select_items = {i: model.NewBoolVar("item_" + str(i)) for i in data["w_default"]}

# constraint: remove exactly 3 items
# TODO: remove exactly 3 items because right now the objective function does not work yet (even without removing any items)
model.Add(sum(dv_select_items[i] for i in dv_select_items) == num_items)

##### numerator equation #####
# x_i * w_i * p_i
xi_wi_pi = model.NewIntVar(0, UB, "xi_wi_pi")
model.Add(xi_wi_pi == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["w_default"][i] * data["chaos"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

##### denominator equation #####
xi_wi = model.NewIntVar(0, UB, "xi_wi")
model.Add(xi_wi == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["w_default"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

y_xi_wi_pi = model.NewIntVar(0, UB, "y_xi_wi_pi")
model.AddDivisionEquality(y_xi_wi_pi, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi)

# set target
model.Maximize(xi_wi_pi)

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

# inspect the solution
objective_function_value = solver.ObjectiveValue()
solution_info = solver.SolutionInfo()

result = [(i, solver.Value(dv_select_items[i])) for i in dv_select_items]
```

It seems that the problem lies within this part:

```
##### denominator equation #####
xi_wi = model.NewIntVar(0, UB, "xi_wi")
model.Add(xi_wi == sum(dv_select_items[i] * data["w_default"][i] for i in dv_select_items))

y_xi_wi_pi = model.NewIntVar(0, UB, "y_xi_wi_pi")
model.AddDivisionEquality(y_xi_wi_pi, xi_wi_pi, xi_wi)
```

No matter how I rephrase this (tried @Bhartendu Awasthi proposal with

```
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(y_x_i_w_i, [y_x_i_w_i, y])
```

first but the objective function always returns 0, although it should be (without removing anything)

```
xi_wi_pi = 16750 
xi_wi = 3750
objective_function_value = 16750 / 3750 = 4,466
```

If we exclude items 3, 4 and 5 the result should be

```
objective_function_value = 7750 / 1250 = 6,2
```

I have no solution at the moment but will try to solve it in the next days.